# Rotate image in PDF using Prawn gem

Tags: ruby, prawn

I am updating an existing Ruby on Rails application and creating a PDF using the rawn gem.

I can rotate `text` and `text_box`es, but I'm unable to rotate images.

Can Prawn be used to rotate images?

The Prawn documentation says you can configure the image dimensions by setting the width and height or by scaling it, but not rotate it.

Answer (score 2):

It [looks like you can](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Graphics/Transformation.html#method-i-rotate)... If for some reason it doesn't work at all, just hit it with something [like this](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) first...